# Conditional row selection in R

Tags: r

I have a df like this

[image]

And I want to select only those rows where VALUE2 and VALUE4 coincide. So, in this example the result should be this:

[image]

Is it possible to do so in R?

Comment: `df[df$VALUE2 == df$VALUE4,] `?

Comment: Too late, but this works also: `library(data.table) setDT(df)[VALUE2 == VALUE4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or much in the same way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(VALUE2 == VALUE4)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use subset with `==`

```
subset(df, VALUE2 == VALUE4)
```